# Carregar informação de grid em textbox em um form que já está aberto c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, formulário, datagridview

Olá estou tentando fazer uma coisa que parece simples mais não estou conseguindo, quero ao clicar em um botão adicionar os dados de um grid vá para outro form que já está aberto. o problema é que só estou conseguindo carregar em um novo form não é isso que quero segue codigo para ajuda:

evento do botão adicionar Form1

```
  private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        frmPedidos frmped = new frmPedidos(CODIGO, NOME, TELEFONE, ENDERECO); 

        CODIGO = int.Parse(dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        NOME = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        TELEFONE = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ENDERECO = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        frmped.Show();// aqui que ele carrega outro form tanto faz se usar ShowDialog ou Show mesmo
    }
```

Form 2

```
 public frmPedidos(int codigo, string nome, string telefone, string endereco)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtCodCliente.Text = codigo.ToString();
        txtNomeCliente.Text = nome;
        txtTelefoneCliente.Text = telefone; 
        txtEndCliente.Text = endereco;


    }
```

Quero preencha no form2 já aberto e não em um novo form pois vou colocar mais outras tabelas que vão fazer o mesmo processo se fizer isso em todas vou perder as informações.

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, você deseja abrir um formulário para fazer uma pesquisa de clientes e retornar o cliente selecionado para o form chamador.

Se for isso mesmo, você pode implementar da seguinte forma:

No Form de Pesquisa:

```
public partial class frmSlaveConsultaCliente : Form
{
    //propriedades com os dados do cliente selecionado
    public int Codigo {get; private set;}
    public string Nome {get; private set;}
    public string Telefone {get; private set;}
    public string Endereco {get; private set;}

    public frmSlaveConsultaCliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Codigo = int.Parse(dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        this.Nome = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        this.Telefone =  dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        this.Endereco =  dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // para indicar ao Form chamador que o usuário adicionou um cliente
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

No Form de Chamador:

```
public partial class frmPedidos : Form
{
    public frmPedidos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btnProcSabor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frmSlaveProd = new frmSlaveConsultaCliente();

        if (frmSlaveProd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        txtCodCliente.Text = frmSlaveProd.Codigo.ToString();
        txtNomeCliente.Text = frmSlaveProd.Nome;
        txtTelefoneCliente.Text = frmSlaveProd.Telefone; 
        txtEndCliente.Text = frmSlaveProd.Endereco;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Fernando desde já agradeço a ajuda assim fiz o que está sugerindo  mais estou com problemas quando coloco a  'var _frmped = new frmPedidos();' no escopo nem consigo abrir o meu form do pedido já da erro quando coloco no evento do botão não acontece nada, ainda estou estudando o que você fez para tenta resolver aqui também mais sem sucesso até o momento. Tem mais alguma dica?

Comment: @Jameson, fiz um pequeno ajuste no código. Já testei e funcionou aqui.

Comment: Então desta maneira funciona no  _frmped.Show();  só que ele abre outro form e o que já está aberto não é preenchido acho que tem que fazer encapsulamento dos textbox mais não sei muito sobre como prosseguir.Se esse for o caso

Comment: Com o código que você postou, não dá para saber como está sendo feito a abertura de `frmPedidos`. Se você estiver abrindo`frmPedidos` antes de abrir Form1, você terá que passá-lo como parâmetro para Form1

Comment: Alterei o código para mostrar como você pode passar o form aberto como parâmetro para Form1

Comment: deu certo com a maneira que você fez deu certinho a unica coisa que não conseguir fazer foi pegar os dados do Cliente que já tinha criado os metodos get e set em classe separada e puxar de la  mais está certinho. Very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ele está assim o form1 frmSlaveConsultaCliente ele é aberto a partir do form2 frmPedidos

```
 public partial class frmSlaveConsultaCliente : Form
{
  //  frmPedidos _frmped = new frmPedidos();
    public frmSlaveConsultaCliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    ConexaoClienteDataContext cc = new ConexaoClienteDataContext();


    public  int CODIGO;
    public  string NOME;

    public string TELEFONE;

    public  string ENDERECO;

    private void frmSlaveConsultaCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListarCliente();


    }

    public void ListarCliente()
    {
        dgvConsultaCliente.DataSource = cc.pListarCliente();
    }

    private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        CODIGO = int.Parse(dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        NOME = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        TELEFONE = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ENDERECO = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        //  _frmped.PreencherCampos(CODIGO, NOME, TELEFONE, ENDERECO);
        frmPedidos.TextBoxcontaine txt = new frmPedidos.TextBoxcontaine();

    }
```

o form2 que é aberto primeiro está assim:

```
 public partial class frmPedidos : Form
{


    public frmPedidos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }


    public void PreencherCampos(int codigo, string nome, string telefone, string endereco)
    {
        txtCodCliente.Text = codigo.ToString();
        txtNomeCliente.Text = nome;
       txtTelefoneCliente.Text = telefone;
        txtEndCliente.Text = endereco;


    }


   // frmSlaveConsultaCliente frmClid = new frmSlaveConsultaCliente();


    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnProcSabor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSlaveConsultaProduto frmSlaveProd = new frmSlaveConsultaProduto();
        frmSlaveProd.Show();
    }
```

O código que você colocou não conseguir implementar ainda. fica dando erros

Comment: acho que agora entendi o que você quer e refiz o meu post. Se a minha resposta estiver correta, sugiro que você altere a sua pergunta inicial para deixá-la mais clara.

Answer (score 0):

Se você descomentar as linhas abaixo funciona, mas acredito que você precisa chamar o evento Refresh do seu form para carregar os dados na tela, tente assim:

```
 public partial class frmSlaveConsultaCliente : Form
{
    frmPedidos _frmped = new frmPedidos();
    public frmSlaveConsultaCliente()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    ConexaoClienteDataContext cc = new ConexaoClienteDataContext();


    public  int CODIGO;
    public  string NOME;

    public string TELEFONE;

    public  string ENDERECO;

    private void frmSlaveConsultaCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListarCliente();


    }

    public void ListarCliente()
    {
        dgvConsultaCliente.DataSource = cc.pListarCliente();
    }

    private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        CODIGO = int.Parse(dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        NOME = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        TELEFONE = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ENDERECO = dgvConsultaCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

        _frmped.PreencherCampos(CODIGO, NOME, TELEFONE, ENDERECO);
        _frmped.Refresh();

    }
```